# MySql Index Optimization - Same query using two different indexes has to look at 11 million more rows - why is this?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

Let's say that we have three tables `Parts`, `Brand`, and `Warehouse` in this obviously contrived example.

Parts has id, brand_id, and warehouse_id
index_parts_on_brand_id
index_parts_on_brand_id_and_warehouse_id

We run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `parts` WHERE `parts`.`brand_id` = {some_id};
```

When I run this query for a brand that has a large number of parts (in this case 7 million) and check out the query plan, I can see mysql using
`index_parts_on_brand_id_and_warehouse_id` index.

If I force mysql to use `index_parts_on_brand_id` like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `parts` FORCE INDEX (index_parts_on_brand_id) WHERE `parts`.`brand_id` = {some_id};
```

When using each index:
`index_parts_on_brand_id`

- type: ref
- extra: Using index
- has to look at 13,012,370 rows **13,012,370**

`index_parts_on_brand_id_and_warehouse_id`

- type: ref
- extra: Using index
- has to look at **2,391,314**

I was surprised to see that the db had to look at almost 11 mil more records when using `index_parts_on_brand_id`...

Why is mysql forced to look at so many extra rows? I would have expected mysql to have to look at the same, or less when using `index_parts_on_brand_id` vs `index_parts_on_brand_id_and_warehouse_id`

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly was the table created, and the indexes created? Please post the DDL.

Comment: It was created using active record in rails migration.

Answer (score 1):

"has to look at 13,012,370 rows" -- This is a fallacy.

`EXPLAIN` *estimates* the numbers it presents to you.  Sometimes they are vary far off.  Don't trust them.

On the other hand, *do trust* `extra: Using index`.  That means that the `INDEX` was "covering", which means that it used the index's BTree and not the data's BTree.  This is good.

But,... It still hast to look at some number of millions of rows.

To get the exact number of rows 'touched', either use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (if available) or use the `Handler` values:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

I really need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a full example of the query.  Here is a common mistake that prevents the use of an index:

```
CREATE TABLE ... brand_id VARCHAR(...) ...

WHERE brand_id = 123
```

The pitfall is comparing a string column to a numeric literal.